# long living programs and their members

Tags: c#

I have a question about long living programs and their members.
I have noticed that in a long living program some objects with functionality like events or `Timers.Timer` stop working after some time (can be days or weeks), and the lifeTime is null meaning there is no lease on them.
have you noticed that, are you all doing something else in long living ?

**UPDATE**
Sorry about there instead of their. but long living programs i mean windows service and programs that run in computer start up and live until the computer shut down.

Comment: What are "long living programs and there (their?) members"?

Comment: Timers should work forever. Have you tried setting up a simple app with a single timer and seeing how long it runs for?

Comment: you mean long living OR long running ?

Comment: He has to be talking about an application that runs as a service...

Comment: Windows Services? applications? you have to provide some more context for this question to make sense.

Comment: Maybe its a bug in your code.  Can't say, since we don't have any code to look at.

Answer (score 2):

No. I've not noticed that they stop working.

Things to check:

Are you catching exceptions without logging or handling them? Refactor.

Do you got memory leaks? A typical error is to subscribe on events for short lived objects but forgetting to unsubscribe. This means that the objects will continue to live since the event subscriber has a reference to it.

Answer (score 2):

For timers, my guess is that you aren't keeping a reference to them, and they're being garbage collected. The docs for [`System.Timers.Timer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) don't *explicitly* mention this, but they do give an example of it being a problem.

Comment: come on jon, of course it has a reference. most of the time its a member inside a singleton object. maybe the lifecycle is over or something else, i catch each exception. maybe if it was on one programs but its happens on a number of proograms.

Comment: by the way as i said i used the `Timers.Timer` class and not the `Threading.Timer` if it makes any difference

Comment: @guyl: Oops, I could have sworn I was looking at System.Timers.Timer. Anyway, I believe the same thing applies. As for your previous "of course" - there's no "of course" about it. You're complaining that something doesn't work, where one would expect it to work. Not keeping a strong reference to a timer is a way that it could behave exactly as you describe, and it would be a reasonably subtle bug. You didn't say anything about it being a member of a singleton. If you're not going to give any sample code where it's a problem, we can't *assume* anything.

Comment: Of course, there is nothing wrong with @guyl code. It is the Timers fault.

Comment: Sorry jon, the "of course" in my head was in a different tone. in writing i can see that it can be understood as a complain. It's strange because it is working for couple of days and then it's stops, No events pop and the timers stops, can it be that the singleton get collected by the GC ?